# Unable to resolve camel-sql/2.19.5: missing requirement

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf

I deployed camel multiple time on karaf and these commands used to work, but today i tried to run applications on Karaf 4.2.0 and getting below error, All dependencies used to get resolve automatically

```
karaf@root()> feature:install camel-sql
org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=camel-sql; type=karaf.featur
e; version="[2.19.5,2.19.5]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=camel-sql)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=2.19.5)(version<=2.19.5))" [caused by: Unable to resolve ca
mel-sql/2.19.5: missing requirement [camel-sql/2.19.5] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=spring-tx; type=karaf.feature; version="[4.1.0,5.0.0)"]
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolutionError.toException(ResolutionError.java:42)
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.doResolve(ResolverImpl.java:391)
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:377)
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:331)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.SubsystemResolver.resolve(SubsystemResolver.java:248)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:388)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1025)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.lambda$doProvisionInThread$13(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:964)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=camel-sql; type=karaf.feature; version="[2.19.5,2.
19.5]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=camel-sql)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=2.19.5)(version<=2.19.5))" [caused by: Unable to resolve camel-sql/2.19.5: missin
g requirement [camel-sql/2.19.5] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=spring-tx; type=karaf.feature; version="[4.1.0,5.0.0)"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry, i just realized in 4.2.0 we have to add below repo to work with spring 4

repo-add mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/spring-legacy/4.2.0/xml/features